# Sample .net core projects no longer deploy to Elastic Beanstalk with VS2017

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, visual-studio-2017

I created a sample .net core web application in VS2017 with all the template defaults.  The only change was to switch it from .netcore1.1 to .netcore1.0  I deployed it to Elastic Beanstalk with the AWS plugin (as I did in VS2015).

When I run it on EB, I get process failure.  Am I missing something simple?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a known issue that is currently being worked on. You can follow along here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/572#issuecomment-286164347